# VBA Reconnect Remembered Network Drive

Tags: excel, vba, wsh

(MS Excel 2016)

I'm trying to find a solution, which can be implemented via vba, to ensure that the network resource for my Excel utility is available and prevent the

> {insert path here} is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name
> is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which
> the file resides.

error message from popping up.

The crux of the problem lies with windows not correctly reconnecting mapped network drives. I have no control over this as IT assigns the mapped drives via group policy, so none of the solutions to correct the underlying issue will help in anyway; however, that does mean that I do know what the drive letter for the mapped resource will always be for my users.  That being said, the only solution that seems to work is having the user open the file explorer and click on the mapped drive and open it there, once that is done, the red "X" over the drive goes away and everything works fine.

I have spent the better part of 2 days trudging through google results and have not yet found a solution.  I have tried

```
Function nVerifyDriveExists(ByVal DriveLetter As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        nVerifyDriveExists = fso.DriveExists(DriveLetter)
        Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

but that doesn't work if the drive has not been manually reconnected by opening it in file explorer

I've tried

```
Sub test()
    Dim nwo As WshNetwork
        Set nwo = New WshNetwork
        nwo.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"
        nwo.MapNetworkDrive "A:", "\\{servername}\shares"
        Set nwo = Nothing
End Sub
```

but that gives me the errors

> Automation Error.
> This network connection does not exist

and

> Automation Error
> The local device name has a remembered connection
> to another network resource.

Is there a way to do this programmatically, or am I just going to have to deal with users contacting me to say that my utility isn't working, for me to just have them open file explorer and click a drive?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but this happens to me too in VBA and Python. My solution is to just use the 'real' path ie: "I:\\" is mapped to "\\cfs01\Engineering"

Comment: I don't completely understand your request, because you did what you can do with the tools you have. Can't you just test if the folder exists and, when it's not available, inform the user with a messagebox? The message should be something like "The path is not available, please manually reconnect it using file explorer".

Comment: It's much simpler to work directly with "\\serverName\shares" than to use a mapped drive (unless there's some reason you can't do that?)

Comment: @TimWilliams  I could do that, was just hoping there was a solution that would reconnect the network share.  But it does appear that what I need to do is work on a solution that will convert the stored path of any save file paths (from previous versions) to UNC paths and then store the new UNC path to prevent this issue in the future

Comment: Yes - the UNC path is fixed (relatively) whereas mapped drives can vary by letter and so make your life more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. A bit shocked to see someone describing exactly my same problem wit the red x. Warcupine's and Tim's answers did the trick. I thought about having VBA open File Explorer at Remote drive then quickly closing it. But mapped drive is way faster and more reliable.